# Apply time offset to get current time

Tags: php

My server has 5 hours difference from my current location time. After I record an event I'd like to display current local time. My time is stored in db as DATETIME value (0000:00:00 00:00:00).

I can get offset time in seconds with PHP like this:

```
$offset = date('Z');
```

So, the time from db will be:

```
$time = '2016-03-31 01:40:13';
```

But if my time is offset by -18000 sec, i.e. -5 hrs, the display time should be

```
2016-03-30 20:40:13
```

So I've attempted:

```
echo date('Y:m:d H:i:s', mktime(strtotime($time + $offset)));
```

But it looks convoluted...

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do but look at the PHP [DateTime Object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 0):

`setlocale(LC_TIME,'YOUR_LOCALE');` for `strftime` formatting

AND

`date_default_timezone_set('YOUR_TIMEZONE');` for [timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) settings